# Publish to MQTT topic in AWS IoT from Ionic 5

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot, ionic5

I am using ionic 5 for a mobile app that runs on iOS and Android. How can I publish a message to an MQTT topic in AWS IoT from Ionic 5? I have generated certificates for the client authentication in AWS IoT already. Are there any libraries available for this?

Comment: Here is a [guide](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/pubsub/getting-started/q/platform/js/) for PubSub library if you use ionic with Amplify.